# Nvidia MX150 grapics driver manjaro linux issue

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, manjaro

Recently I installed Manjaro Linux in my acer-515-51G-52ZR system. While checking hardware configuration I found Nvidia Intel bumblebee is not installed. So while i tried to install, I got the below error:

> Error: config 'video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-bumblebee' conflicts with config(s): video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee"

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: How is your MX150 performing on manjaro, I cant for my life install bumblebee on it! Getting black screen after the install.

Comment: Hybrid drivers are ok. But while opening chrome for the first time its very slow. It tooks more than 30 seconds to open chrome for the first time.

Comment: Could you paste your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and your `/etc/X11/mhwd.d/intel.conf ` files. Also, we are discussing this at the forum [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/stable-update-2018-05-17-gcc8-gimp-kde-gnome-deepin-firefox/47510/93?u=lf_araujo)

Comment: where you want to paste the code?

Comment: Could you link to a pastebin either here or at the forum? Thank you!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qTHTqLTw

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xLbj7R43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually remove `video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee`,
install `video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-bumblebee`, then reboot :

```
sudo mhwd -r pci video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee
sudo mhwd -i pci video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-bumblebee
```